# Can Terry Gou provide guarantees of the necessary independence for the role of president of Taiwan?

Tags: taiwan

I saw in the news that Foxconn founder [Terry Gou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Gou) will run as a third party candidate in the 2024 Taiwanese presidential election.

As far as I know he is still a major shareholder of Foxconn. [This link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOgsrK1oGBAxUOS_EDHej-BD8QFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.foxconn.com%2Fs3%2Freports%2Fshareholders-meetings%2F2021%2F%25E4%25B8%25BB%25E8%25A6%2581%25E8%2582%25A1%25E6%259D%25B1%25E5%2590%258D%25E5%2596%25AE(EN).pdf&usg=AOvVaw36DYEaT5OyDeE1dfSgc-SZ&opi=89978449)* may not be up to date, but lists his participation to almost 10% of the company. As it is the company is exposed to pressure from the Chinese government since they have factories in China and from the US corporations that are its major clients.

With such a big part of his wealth exposed to external pressure can Terry Gou guarantee to be as much independent as the president of a nation with a population of more than 23 million people is supposed to be?

BTW I am aware that Terry Gou is not a supporter of the independence movement. In this question independence means the ability to make political decisions on the ground of the political situation without the involvement of personal issues.

[*] Apologies for the google link. I could not find the direct link.

Comment: Is there a legal requirement to prove that independence? For example, forbidding Taiwanese candidates who have strong ties with the PRC? Otherwise, it seems that you are asking either "how can a Taiwanese voter be sure that Gou will not pressured by the PRC?" To which the answer is up to each Taiwanese voter. Or "How can Gou be sure himself that he will not be pressured by the PRC?", to which nobody but Gou may ask (how much does Gou value his assets in the PRC in relation to his political ideas?)

Comment: Voting to close - This question cannot be answered factually. While Foxconn factories in China do certainly make him vulnerable to certain political pressures from China, can anyone  genuinely predict how he will react to it? Even if you can offer past example of him giving in to pressure to the Chinese, note that would have happened when he was a businessman and not as a politician. As a President, the circumstances completely change and he may even actually be able to oppose Chinese pressure.